# Can I create a Maven project that expects anyone who includes it to have an implementation of an arbitrary Java-ee 6 library?

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I am creating a project that will be useful for anyone with a java-ee environment. I wan't to include the bare bones java-ee interface library in my project to allow me to code with all of the EJB annotations but i would rather make it's scope `provided` so as not to import all the classes into my project.

Is there a way I can make this dependency and require any user to have a java-ee library or do I have to make something like maven profiles that activate when it detects each server type, (i.e. one for jboss, one for glassfish, websphere, etc...).

my pom looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>project-that-wants-users-to-have-javaee-libraries</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-Pre-alpha</version>

    <dependencies>
        ....
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>6.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**EDIT:** just to clarify what I Am asking, Say I have a maven project like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testEJBProject</artifactId>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-all-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>project-that-wants-users-to-have-javaee-libraries</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-Pre-alpha</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.4.Final</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

will the dependency in my code be satisfied at runtime even though i'm specifically using the jboss-javaee-all-6.0 api and plugin?

Comment: You can depend on just the APIs, but you'll need to specify *which* APIs (e.g., `javax.validation`, the Servlet API).

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking here.  Can you explain why you need something more than what you have already got?  Why the `provided` dependency is not sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is my understanding that specifying the java api's and scoping them to provided will cause the dependency to expect anything using it to already have the implementations of those api's on the class path. you specify a dependency as `provided` like so:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>tobeprovidedproject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```